# Calculating date difference of subsequent rows based on each group in R

Tags: r, datetime, group-by, grouping, datediff

I have a sample table which looks somewhat like this:

```
| Date       | Vendor_Id | Requisitioner | Amount |
|------------|:---------:|--------------:|--------|
| 1/17/2019  |     98    |          John | 2405   |
| 4/30/2019  |    1320   |          Dave | 1420   |
| 11/29/2018 |    3887   |       Michele | 596    |
| 11/29/2018 | 3887      | Michele       | 960    |
| 11/29/2018 | 3887      | Michele       | 1158   |
| 9/21/2018  | 4919      | James         | 857    |
| 10/25/2018 | 4919      | Paul          | 1162   |
| 10/26/2018 | 4919      | Echo          | 726    |
| 10/26/2018 | 4919      | Echo          | 726    |
| 10/29/2018 | 4919      | Andrew        | 532    |
| 10/29/2018 | 4919      | Andrew        | 532    |
| 11/12/2018 | 4919      | Carlos        | 954    |
| 5/21/2018  | 2111      | June          | 3580   |
| 5/23/2018  | 7420      | Justin        | 224    |
| 5/24/2018  | 1187      | Sylvia        | 3442   |
| 5/25/2018  | 1187      | Sylvia        | 4167   |
| 5/30/2018  | 3456      | Ama           | 4580   |
```

Based on each requisitioner and vendor id, I need to find the difference in the date such that it should be something like this:

```
| Date       | Vendor_Id | Requisitioner | Amount | Date_Diff |
|------------|:---------:|--------------:|--------|-----------|
| 1/17/2019  |     98    |          John | 2405   | NA        |
| 4/30/2019  |    1320   |          Dave | 1420   | 103       |
| 11/29/2018 |    3887   |       Michele | 596    | NA        |
| 11/29/2018 | 3887      | Michele       | 960    | 0         |
| 11/29/2018 | 3887      | Michele       | 1158   | 0         |
| 9/21/2018  | 4919      | James         | 857    | NA        |
| 10/25/2018 | 4919      | Paul          | 1162   | NA        |
| 10/26/2018 | 4919      | Paul          | 726    | 1         |
| 10/26/2018 | 4919      | Paul          | 726    | 0         |
| 10/29/2018 | 4919      | Paul          | 532    | 3         |
| 10/29/2018 | 4919      | Paul          | 532    | 0         |
| 11/12/2018 | 4917      | Carlos        | 954    | NA        |
| 5/21/2018  | 2111      | Justin        | 3580   | NA        |
| 5/23/2018  | 7420      | Justin        | 224    | 2         |
| 5/24/2018  | 1187      | Sylvia        | 3442   | NA        |
| 5/25/2018  | 1187      | Sylvia        | 4167   | 1         |
| 5/30/2018  | 3456      | Ama           | 4580   | NA        |
```

Now, if the difference in the date is <=3 days within each requisitioner and vendor id, and sum of the amount is >5000, I need to create a subset of that. The final output should be something like this:

```
| Date      | Vendor_Id | Requisitioner | Amount | Date_Diff |
|-----------|:---------:|--------------:|--------|-----------|
| 5/24/2018 |    1187   |        Sylvia | 3442   | NA        |
| 5/25/2018 |    1187   |        Sylvia | 4167   | 1         |
```

Initially, when I tried working with date difference, I used the following code:

```
df=df %>% mutate(diffdate= difftime(Date,lag(Date,1)))
```

However, the difference doesn't make sense as they are huge numbers such as 86400 and some huge random numbers. I tried the above code when data type for 'Date' field was initially Posixct. Later when I changed it to 'Date' data type, the date differences were still the same huge random numbers. 
Also, is it possible to group the date differences based on requisitioners and vendor id's as mentioned in the 2nd table above?

EDIT:
I'm coming across a new challenge now. In the problem set, I need to filter out the values whose date differences are less than 3 days. Let us assume that the table with date difference appears something like this:

```
| MasterCalendarDate | Vendor_Id | Requisitioner | Amount | diffdate |
|--------------------|:---------:|--------------:|--------|----------|
| 1/17/2019          |     98    |          John | 2405   | #N/A     |
| 4/30/2019          |    1320   |          Dave | 1420   | 103      |
| 11/29/2018         | 3887      | Michele       | 596    | #N/A     |
| 11/29/2018         | 3887      | Michele       | 960    | 0        |
| 11/29/2018         | 3887      | Michele       | 1158   | 0        |
| 9/21/2018          | 4919      | Paul          | 857    | #N/A     |
| 10/25/2018         | 4919      | Paul          | 1162   | 34       |
| 10/26/2018         | 4919      | Paul          | 726    | 1        |
| 10/26/2018         | 4919      | Paul          | 726    | 0        |
```

When we look at the requisitioner 'Paul', the date diff between 9/21/2018 and 10/25/2018 is 34 and between that of 10/25/2018 and 10/26/2018 is 1 day. However, when I filter the data for date difference <=3 days, I miss out on 10/25/2018 because of 34 days difference. I have multiple such occurrences. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to convert your date variable using `as.Date()`, then you can compute the lagged time difference using `difftime()`.

```r
# create toy data frame
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(paste(sample(2018:2019,100,T),
                            sample(1:12,100,T),
                            sample(1:28,100,T),sep = '-')),
                 req=sample(letters[1:10],100,T),
                 amount=sample(100:10000,100,T))

# compute lagged time difference in days -- diff output is numeric
df %>% arrange(req,date) %>% group_by(req) %>% 
  mutate(diff=as.numeric(difftime(date,lag(date),units='days')))

# as above plus filtering based on time difference and amount
df %>% arrange(req,date) %>% group_by(req) %>% 
  mutate(diff=as.numeric(difftime(date,lag(date),units='days'))) %>% 
  filter(diff<10 | is.na(diff), amount>5000)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   req [7]
  date       req   amount  diff
  <date>     <fct>  <int> <dbl>
1 2018-05-13 a       9062    NA
2 2019-05-07 b       9946     2
3 2018-02-03 e       5697    NA
4 2018-03-12 g       7093    NA
5 2019-05-16 g       5631     3
6 2018-03-06 h       7114     6
7 2018-08-12 i       5151     6
8 2018-04-03 j       7738     8
```

Comment: I had converted the date type using as.Date(), but it produced same random huge numbers.

Comment: If you are reading in your data from Excel, then you may need to set the `origin` when converting to date variables. For example, the origin date when reading data from Excel on Macs is typically `origin='1899-12-30'`. Otherwise, you will keep the numeric value that Excel uses and then get huge numbers.

Comment: I'm now getting the correct date difference. I guess it was because I had earlier not written as.numeric() with difftime(). Thank you!

Comment: I have come across a new difficulty which I have posted under EDIT in the question. Could you please have a look at it and see if there's a potential solution to it or not? TIA!

Comment: What you want seems to contradict the purpose of creating the `diffdate` variable and then filtering day<=3. Why do you want to keep that date (10/25/2018) if the difference is 34 days?

Comment: The purpose of this problem set is to identify similar transactions or orders requested by requisitioners from same vendors that have occurred in a span of 3 day difference. So, one approach I could think of was to calculate the date difference. But, after calculating date difference, I came across the problem mentioned above.